# I am having `Error: Cannot find module 'react'` on running `next dev` while setting up vercel/postgres

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, next.js13

I was trying to create a table in @vercel/postgres database. the quickstart guide documentation in the following link
https://vercel.com/docs/storage/vercel-postgres/quickstart

at step 4 shows how the table is created and says `next dev` which I am getting a response on the terminal as follows:

> *The module 'react' was not found. Next.js requires that you include it in 'dependencies' of your 'package.json'*

> *throw err;*
> ^

> *Error: Cannot find module 'react'*
> ...
> code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',*

I already have react and react-dom in my package.json file installed.

I tried deleting node_modules and package_lock.json and npm install which seems to not solve the problem. I am using node.js 18.17.1

can anyone help please?

Comment: Can you share link to Repository(if openly available). I want to recreate this.

Comment: yeah sure.
https://github.com/fet7/Bus-Ticketing-Admin-dashboard.git

Comment: Is your site working fine without connecting to Database?

Comment: Also, Can you share your updated code.

Comment: I have updated the code. yup it works fine.

Comment: https://mobts-fet7.vercel.app/

if this helps

Answer (score 0):

Check your `package.json` file. If all of your libraies are installed then try clearing cache :

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then install dependencies using:

```
npm i
```

Then it must run

Comment: tried this a couple of times. react and react-dom dependencies are there. tried cleaning cache also. none of them seems to work yet. thanks for your help though.